# Changing /etc/passwd in SSH User

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, unix, password

I've got an Amazon EC2 instance running. It's an Ubuntu 14.04. I connect using Putty SSH. I use the key/certificates I got when I created the instance to authenticate my connection. This is all done through a user called **ubuntu** created when I launched the instanced.

My question is that user **ubuntu** currently has `/bin/bash` in `/etc/passwd`. I want to change it to `/bin/false`. If I make the change, will I be *forbidden from making the SSH connection?* I don't want to loose connection to the instance, SSH is the only way to get in.

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: *I want to change it to /bin/false.*  You should explain your reasoning for wanting to make this change. There's almost certainly a more correct way to accomplish whatever it is that you have in mind than this.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want to disable the default `ubuntu` user (a reasonable thing to do), you will need to add another user to the system that you will use to connect via SSH. Needless to say, this second user should have sudo privileges.